# Clubhouse drop audio chat api

Tags: api, social-media, clubhouse

i have an api from ClubHouse Audio Chat , and clubhouseapi.com/api/get_followers?page_size=2&page=2
we can pass 2 params `page_size` and `page` Number , it will return

```
{
    "users": [
    ],
    "count": 400,
    "next": 3,
    "previous": 1,
    "success": true
}
```

but only send me count 400 , and did not get back more than 400 followers i need to get All Followers to track user did not follow back me

is there any way to get more follower list?
or Compare All Followings to know their follows me too

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
clubhouseapi.com/api/get_followers?user_id=931394056&page_size=120&page=1
```

I create a list of clubhouse API end-points, you can see below link

[clubhouse-api](https://github.com/ehsanghaffarii/clubhouse-cli)

I find a postman collection of clubhouse API end-points, that are almost end-points on Clubhouse API

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it